# Android Notification Not working with broadcast. It only works in debug mode

Tags: android, android-notifications

This works in an older version of Android, but Android 7 and 8 generates this error.

I have tried many solutions with exact implementation.

I want my broadcast to listen according to specific date and time to raise the notification.

Comment: Post your Error logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Zoe. My question is totally different. It's Logical error.